# SwitchCompat right of TextView gets pushed out of sight

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a CardView Layout with two TextViews and a SwitchCompat.
Right now the switch is left and the texts are right of it (vertically). I want this layout the opposite way, like for example in the Android Notification Settings of an app:
[image: Google Navigation Settings, that's how I want it to be]

My problem is, that when I "turn my current layout around", the switch gets pushed out to the right when the textView gets too long.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/switch_card"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/title_card"
        android:textColor="@color/text_black"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_reminder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/switch_card"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/reminder_card"
        android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can you please help me changing my layout that it fits the one of the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this : the trick to align the SwitchCompat to the righParent and put some margin to the TextView's you are using so they do not overlap the SwitchCompat

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/relative">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/switch_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/title_card"
            android:textColor="@color/text_black"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_reminder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView_title"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/reminder_card"
            android:textColor="@color/text_grey"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this was helpful

Good luck !

Comment: It really was helpful, thanks very much. Seems a but hacky, but it does to job.